# custom code generation in xtext

Tags: code-generation, xtext

I am using Xtext do define a new language. I wish to generate code from this language, however I do not want to use the automatically suggested doGenerate function. Instead, I need to use a java code (not Xtend), that I can call from the build process.

Of course in that java code I want to be able to use the 'resource' that is passed to the original suggested function, so I can access all the information from the DSL's code.

Comment: How do I set a java genrator for my Xtext DSL.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe by default the generator is implementation is an xtend file but there is nothing stopping you from changing this to a java file, you just need to override the binding in your [LanguageName]RuntimeModule class as follows:-

```
public class ExampleRuntimeModule extends com.example.AbstractExampleRuntimeModule {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends IGenerator> bindIGenerator() {
        return YourOwnGenerator.class;
    }
}
```

Where YourOwnGenerator should implement IGenerator.